# Create a custom HtmlHelper implementing HTML5 client-side validation for MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Since HTML5 support has become so wide nowadays, I thought about disabling the default MVC5 client-side validation system based on jQuery.validate and creating a set of custom HtmlHelpers that will simply add the `required="required"` attribute to the `<input>` field when the ViewModel property is decorated with the `[Required]` attribute.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Html5TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var required = typeof(TProperty).GetProperties().Any(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(RequiredAttribute)));

        var requiredAttribute = required ? new {required = "required"} : null;

        var html = new StringBuilder();

        helper.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
        html.Append(helper.TextBoxFor(expression, requiredAttribute));
        helper.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled = true;

        return new MvcHtmlString(html.ToString());
    }
```

It works pretty well, the only problem is that the `required` variable is always false, even if the ViewModel property is set as `[Required]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData); if (metaData.IsRequired) { .... };` (`.GetProperties()` wont work if your property is `string`)

Comment: Oh I see... I didn't think of that, thank you very much